# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'contains'

Tags: javascript

I have written the below code in Master Page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            if (window.location.pathname.contains('Page1.aspx')) {
                var js = document.createElement("script");

                js.type = "text/javascript";
                js.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js';


            }
            if (window.location.pathname.contains('Page2.aspx')) {
                var js = document.createElement("script");

                js.type = "text/javascript";
                js.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js';


            }    

        </script>
```

In asp.net application, I have three pages page1, page2,page3 which are inherited by the same Master Page. When I am trying to access the page3, it is displaying error:
"JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'contains'"

Comment: Why are you using different versions of jQuery on two pages?

Comment: because of jquery conflict in Master Page.

Answer (score 10):

Unless you have defined it yourself (which you haven't), there's no such thing as `contains()` for strings<sup>1</sup>. Use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), which is practically the same thing.

Example:

```
console.log('abcdefg'.includes('def')); // true
console.log('abcdefg'.includes('ghi')); // false
```

If you have to support older browsers (like Internet Explorer), use `indexOf()`:

```
console.log('abcdefg'.indexOf('def') !== -1); // true
console.log('abcdefg'.indexOf('ghi') !== -1); // false
```

Anyway, it is a horrible idea to use two different versions of jQuery on two pages - avoid it where possible.

---

<sup>1:</sup> Technically this isn't 100% true: at one point there was a built-in `contains()` function, but it was renamed to `includes()` [for compatibility reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510110/javascript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-contains/19510144#19510144).